# Adding regular php file to site

Tags: php, templates, filesystem

How do I create a page(in wordpress theme folder) so that it can be accessed on my site as `examplepage.com/somepost.php`?

I can see it as `examplepage.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/somepost.php` but is there any way to cut off the path? Placing the file in the root folder is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn’t really how WordPress is supposed to work. Why is the root folder not an option?

Comment: You would want to route the request through WordPress, having standalone PHP files that are opened directly in a browser has security and maintenance issues, as well as losing a lot of benefits. What does this PHP file do?

Comment: In this situation the security part is not important. Would like to know how/if it could be done.

Comment: @Zae I disagree, but, there are several methods of integrating code like that into WP, and not all of them are appropriate for all uses. The use case is important to know, else you might get an innapropriate answer. E.g. is this a template? A form handler? AJAX endpoint? etc You may not think it important, but it's super critical info to know, otherwise you're either going to get an extremely long winded generic answer that most people won't be bothered typing, that heavily hedges its bets, or, an answer that only applies to certain conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this by setting up a redirect. If you're using an Apache server, for your example, you would add this to .htaccess above the WordPress block:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule somepost.php ^/somepost/
```

It's much more common, and recommended, to create a PHP file *and* a Page (or other post type) within wp-admin). This will still run all of your PHP code, and has the added benefit of automatically including all the WordPress functionality as opposed to an orphan PHP file. In somepost.php in your theme folder:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Show Some Post
*/
// all your PHP here
?>
```

then within wp-admin, actually create a Page (or another post type that supports page-attributes) and select this particular Page Template. You will then have a URL such as http://examplepage.com/somepost/.

Answer (score 0):

As [WebElaine](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/340332/89412) said, it's common practice to create a [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) in your theme and then create a page in your WordPress dashboard and select the template you just created.

You can also create a PHP file in your theme and name it *page-some-post.php* and then create a page in your dashboard named *Some Post*.